# JQuery Flowchart links(connectors) display in more intuitue way

Tags: jquery, svg, flowchart, jquery-svg

I am using Jquery flowchart [Flowchart](https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.flowchart) . While connecting two operators instead of curved lines I made it to normal lines by converting C to L while generating path.

```
linkData.internal.els.path.setAttribute("d", 'M'+bezierFromX+','+(fromY)+' L'+(fromX + offsetFromX + distanceFromArrow + bezierIntensity)+','+fromY+' '+(toX - bezierIntensity)+','+toY+' '+bezierToX+','+toY);
```

Now, while connecting two operators the lines needs to be displayed in more intuitive way i.e., the connectors needs to be shown in front and perpendicular way like in [jsplumb](http://www.lively-kernel.org/repository/webwerkstatt/users/tmohr/libs/jsPlumb/demo/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html).

PFA image for current appearence of my links[image]

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Anyone found a way to do this ?